# Why does pam_mount ask for password?

Tags: mount, password, pam

I used the `pam-auth-update` tool in order to enable some pam configuration profiles:

```
 PAM configuration 
 PAM profiles to enable:
    [*] encfs encrypted home directories           
    [*] Unix authentication                             
    [*] Mount volumes for user                         
    [*] GNOME Keyring Daemon - Login keyring management  
    [*] ConsoleKit Session Management
```

All the features work as expected, but there's one thing -- the `Mount volumes for user` option seems to affect the `su` command.

I added the following line to `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` file:

```
<volume user="morfik" fstype="fuse" path="encfs#/media/Server/Dropbox.encfs/Dropbox/encrypted" mountpoint="/media/Server/Dropbox" />
```

and when I type in a terminal `su morfik` (as root), there's shouldn't be any password prompt, but instead I see this:

```
# su morfik
reenter password for pam_mount:
```

If I unchecked the `Mount volumes for user` option in the menu above, everything seems to be file and the `reenter password` disappears. I tried to play with `/etc/pam.d/` files, but I don't have any experience with PAM, and I wasn't able to make it work.

Does anyone know what has to be changed in these files?

**UPDATE#1**

This is the content of `/etc/pam.d` directory:

```
# ls -al /etc/pam.d/
total 104K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Mar 21 16:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 153 root root  12K Mar 21 16:11 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  197 Sep  8  2013 atd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  384 May 25  2012 chfn
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   92 May 25  2012 chpasswd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  581 May 25  2012 chsh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.2K Mar 20 17:35 common-account
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.3K Mar 20 17:35 common-auth
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5K Mar 20 17:35 common-password
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.3K Mar 20 17:35 common-session
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.2K Mar 20 17:35 common-session-noninteractive
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  527 Jul  3  2012 cron
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   69 Jul 16  2013 cups-daemon
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 4.8K Mar  5 10:18 login
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   92 May 25  2012 newusers
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  520 Jul 22  2008 other
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  147 Feb 13 07:15 passwd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  255 Oct 15 18:40 polkit-1
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   84 Dec 27 12:40 samba
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.1K Feb 15 03:11 sshd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.3K May 25  2012 su
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   95 Jan 15 22:58 sudo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  108 Oct 19 23:42 xscreensaver
```

There's no file `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.

I checked what files have `pam_mount` in their content, and I got this:

```
# egrep -i pam_mount *
common-auth:auth        optional        pam_mount.so
common-session:session  optional        pam_mount.so
```

The content of the files:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    sufficient              pam_encfs.so 
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_mount.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

and:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session - session-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of sessions of *any* kind (both interactive and
# non-interactive).
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional    pam_mount.so 
session optional            pam_ck_connector.so nox11
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

**UPDATE#2**

I'm using Debian testing. I tried to change the position of `pam_mount`, but it's always the same. I've read some sections of the manual, and there was something like:

> ```
>  When "sufficient" is used in the second column, you must make sure that
>    pam_mount is added before this entry. Otherwise pam_mount will not  get
>    executed  should  a  previous  PAM module succeed. Also be aware of the
>    "include" statements. These make PAM look into the specified  file.  If
>    there is a "sufficient" statement, then the pam_mount entry must either
>    be in the included file before the "sufficient" statement or before the
>    "include" statement.
> ```

I even added `pam_mount` to the `/etc/pam.d/su` file to check if this makes any difference, but it doesn't matter. If `pam_mount` if first, like they say, instead of a password prompt, I get `pam_mount password` prompt when I log to my system, and it still asks for password when I try `su morfik`

Comment: Have you solved this yet?

Comment: Actually I stopped using encfs long time ago, and I didn't solve the problem in the past. I've just installed the appropriate PAM module, and when I "su" to the user in question from root, there's no password prompt. But when I add a volume line to the `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` file, the prompt starts to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the same problem.

Turns out the problem is solved by adding the `disable_interactive` option next to `pam_mount.so` in the config files ( `/etc/pam.d/common-{auth,session}`).

It comes right after `pam_mount.so` and the options are separated with spaces (from the `so` file name and between each two options).

When the `pam_mount.so` code gets executed upon a login,  it'll receive the password from the top of the stack and use that password to decrypt your volume.

When you're doing `su` from a root session, no password is required and therefore `pam_mount.so` will not get any password. So, without the `disable_interactive` option, it will try to obtain the password.

Fortunately, as you can see from https://sourceforge.net/p/pam-mount/pam-mount/ci/master/tree/src/pam_mount.c , line 493, `pam_mount` will try to proceed even without a password, which is good, because the password isn't needed if the volume is already unlocked and mounted.

Comment: I tested partially the parameter because I don't use `encfs` anymore. I just created the dirs and installed appropriate PAM modules. After adding "disable_interactive" to the two files, it actually stopped from showing the password prompt. I'm not sure whether the "mount failed" message is because of the password or because there's no "encfs directory". Anyways I was managed to switch user without a password. So I accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Total guess but have a look at your `/etc/pam.d/*` files and make sure that any PAM configurations related to `pam_mount` are setup as follows:

```
auth optional pam_mount.so
...
auth include system-auth use_first_pass
...
session optional pam_mount.so
```

This would seem to be backed up by the `pam_mount.conf` man page:

*excerpt*

```
Messages
   <msg-authpw>pam_mount password:</msg-authpw>
        When  pam_mount cannot obtain a password through PAM, or is 
        configured to not do so in the first place, and is configured to ask 
        for a password interactively as a replacement, this prompt  will be 
        shown.

   <msg-sessionpw>reenter...:</msg-sessionpw>
        In  case  the  'session' PAM block does not have the password (e.g. 
        on su from root to user), it will ask again. This prompt can also be 
        customized.
```

**NOTE:** The order of the `/etc/pam.d/*` configuration files is also referenced here in this ArchLinux Wiki topic titled: [Pam mount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pam_mount).

#### References

- [Why must I reenter my password for pam_mount?](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=160010)
- [pam mount - my password prompt now says pam_mount password:](https://superuser.com/questions/246188/pam-mount-my-password-prompt-now-says-pam-mount-password)

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - I'm not sure if you're using Debian or Ubuntu but if you take a look at the man page for `pam_mount` there are several examples on how to structure your PAM order using this module. Can you take a look at that and compare it to your `/etc/pam.d/*` files? I'm expecting that you need to change around he PAM stacks. Can you run this: `strace -s 2000 -o su.log su morfik` so we can see which rules are tripping it up?

Comment: I updated the question.